# Wordpress e-commerce theme conflict?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have installed the [shopp plugin](http://shopplugin.net/) for WordPress.

I have also purchased the [FlexiShop theme](http://themeforest.net/item/wp-flexishop-a-versatile-wp-ecommerce-theme/137144) (which is primarily for the wp e-commerce plugin).

The issue I'm having is with integrating the Flexishop theme with the shopp plugin. I know Flexishop was built for wp e-commerce, however, e-commerce is limited in its functionality, which is why I have now gone with shopp.
I purchased the theme and I don't want it to go to waste.

Has anyone achieved something similar or could they point me in the right direction to get this theme to work with shopp plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: What exact issue are you having?

Comment: @scompt.com: I have tried to just install the theme and because Flexishop relies on e-commerce and gold cart functions, it has a tonne of issues. What would be the best way to implement the theme for Shopp plugin? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the synergies between two different plugins like those two are very few. If you really like the way your theme looks though, you can always grab its markup code a reconstruct the theme with Shopp template tags & functions.

Approaching this is a lot like making a new theme entirely. You would need to know HTML, CSS and PHP; If you do, the job can largely be reduced to copy & paste by downloading a theme for Shopp and then work through template file by template file, replacing the existing markup code with the one from you theme. But be aware that if Shopp has functionality that was not included in WP E-commerce, your theme will likely not have provided styles for it.